# writing a for loop in R for a special case

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

If some data frame which contains values like

```
a
1
5
7
9
```

data frame b needs to be extracted from data frame a like

```
If a is less than equals to 10 than b is 1:10
If a is less than equals to 14 than b is 11:14
If a is less than equals to 29 than b is 15:29
```

and the result should reflect like

```
b
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Any leads will be appreciated

Comment: It is not clear about the condition.

Comment: Can you provide the output that you would like ?

Comment: i have a column of some numbers and i need an output like b dataframe as shown in query. that if a is less or equal to  44640 then reflect b like 1:44640

Comment: You don't need to show a big example, just a small one to convey what you want.

Comment: Do you just want `cut(a$variable, breaks=c(1,44640,86400,131040), include.lowest=TRUE)` or something similar?

Comment: i need something similar like i have given a column in data frame so i want to include all missing intergers but by putting a maximum limit

Comment: What are those `..` in the second dataset?  When you say that a is less than equal to 10,  I guess the max value is less than 10, right?

Comment: it is simply means 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Comment: Perhaps `m1 <- max(df1$a);if(m1 < 10) 1:10 else if(m1 < 14) 11:14 else 15:29`

Comment: yes, and in further cases if max value is less than 14 than it should reflect 11 12 13 14 only regardless to any value lower than this

Comment: this function is reflecting only 1 value i.e. 9 in this case

Comment: yes, here are taking the max value and it does reflect for the whole dataset, right

Comment: @RVij what do you mean of `a` is less than 44640: all elements of `a` or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try

```
f1 <- function(x){
       v1 <- max(x)
       v2 <- if(v1 < 10) 1:10 else if(v1 < 14) 11:14 else 15:29 
       data.frame(b = v2)
}

f1(df1$a)
#    b
#1   1
#2   2
#3   3
#4   4
#5   5
#6   6
#7   7
#8   8
#9   9
#10 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you want all the values of `a` less than 10 then `b = 1:10`,  if all the values of `a` less than 14 then `b = 11:14` and if all the value of `a` less than 29 then `b = 15:29`: Please check the code below for details

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,5,7,9))

if (sum(df$a < 10) == nrow(df)) {
b = data.frame(1:10)
} else if (sum(df$a < 14) == nrow(df)) {
b = data.frame(11:14)
} else if (sum(df$a < 29) == nrow(df)) {
b = data.frame(15:29)
}
```

Out of above code is:

```
> b
   X1.10
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      6
7      7
8      8
9      9
10    10
```

Hope this will help you, otherwise let me know your exact requirements.